# List Item not getting added

Tags: reactjs

Take a look at the code below,
Question is, Why a new list item is not getting added on click of "Add to List" ?

```
function SuperList(props) {
  const liVals = [{name:"One"}, {name:"Two"}, {name:"Three"}, {name:"Four"}, {name:"Five"}];
  const [liValues, up] = useState(liVals);
  function AddToList() {
      liValues.concat({name:"Six"});
      liValues.push({name:"Six"});
      alert(liValues.map(el => "  " + el.name));
      up(liValues);
}

  return (<>
    <ul>
      {liValues.map((l) => <li>{l.name}</li>)}
      </ul>
      <button onClick={AddToList}>Add to List</button>
    </>
  );
} 


createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
      <>
      <SuperList/>
      </>
);
```

Comment: Array.prototype.concat() returns new array, doesn't modify the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

```
  function AddToList() {
      up((prevState) => {
        let newState = [...prevState, { name : "six"}]
        return [...newState];
      });
   }
```

Comment: Did you test it ? On click its emptying the page

Comment: While possibly correct, a code-only answer helps the person who asked the question, it doesn't do them or future visitors any good.   Please consider improving your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function SuperList(props) {
  const liVals = [{name:"One"}, {name:"Two"}, {name:"Three"}, {name:"Four"}, {name:"Five"}];
  const [liValues, up] = useState(liVals);
  const AddToList = () => {
    up((state)=> [...state, {name: "Six"},{name: "Seven"}]);
  }
  return (<>
    <ul>
      {liValues.map((l) => <li>{l.name}</li>)}
      </ul>
      <button onClick={AddToList}>Add to List</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`liValues.concat({name:"Six"})` concat method returns new array and does not modify the existing one.
And you are pushing `liValues.push({name:"Six"})` new obj to the livalues, it's better to use `useState()` or `setState()`, because they will trigger re-render.
Check [Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

```
function AddToList() {
  const newLiValues = liValues.concat({name:"Six"});
  //alert(liValues.map(el => "  " + el.name));
  up(newLiValues);
}
```